# UILabelView cropping when expanded, but renders fully when inspected in view hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c

Image 1 shows issue. label has flexible width & height constrains, also we adding fix width & height to expand with. in View hierarchy it shows fully expanded as expected, but issue in real view:

[image]

Image 2 shows fully expanded label in View hierarchy:

[image]

Lable code

```
  self.textLabel = [[RAVerticallyAlignedLabel alloc] initWithFrame: self.bounds andVerticalTextAlignment: [self verticalTextAlignment]];
    self.textLabel.backgroundColor = ClearColour;
    self.textLabel.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    self.textLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    self.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    
    viewToTruncate = self.textLabel;
```

```
textWidth = MAX(MIN(screenSize.width - 20, [label.text sizeWithAttributes: @{NSFontAttributeName : label.font}].width + 10);

[UIView animateWithDuration: 0.3 animations: ^
         {
    self->containerView.frame = CGRectMake(xPos, top , MIN(textWidth, screenSize.width - 2 * RAPadding), newTextviewHeight);
// Container view is added inside scroll view

    self->containerView.layer.shadowRadius = kRATruncationUtiltityShadowRadius;
    self->containerView.layer.shadowOpacity = kRATruncationUtiltityShadowOpacity;
    self->containerView.layer.shadowOffset = kRATruncationUtiltityShadowOffset;
    self->containerView.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect: self->containerView.bounds].CGPath;
    self->containerView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;

    self->viewToExpand.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, textWidth + componentContentWidth, self->containerView.height);
//viewToExpand is UILable, added inside container view

   self->viewToExpand.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
   self->viewToExpand.layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor;
   self->viewToExpand.layer.backgroundColor = backgroundColor.CGColor;
  }];
```

Comment: Please include more information like for example a code sample. Also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: hi @frankenapps code details added.. Thanks

Comment: @KimtiPatel - the label is clearly extending outside the bounds of its superview. It looks like you are mixing auto-layout / constraints with explicit frame sizing, which will be problematic. Tough to say without knowing exactly what you're trying to do, but you *should* be able to handle your layout ***without*** those size calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Found issue fix, it size wasn't issue but "gradientMask" was playing up on expand as below:

```
CAGradientLayer *gradientMask = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradientMask.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, viewToTruncate.width, viewToTruncate.height);
    gradientMask.colors = @[(id)WhiteColour.CGColor,(id)WhiteColour.CGColor, (id)ClearColour.CGColor];
    gradientMask.locations = @[@0, @(locationOfFade), @1];
    viewToTruncate.layer.mask = gradientMask;
```

removing mask on expand , it was rendering as expected.